# adding (|) functionality to determiner on GF

Tags: gf

On GF writing sentences' tree often encounter many options where multiple prepositions could be used in the same tree such as

**Download it on my phone**

**Download it to my phone**

**Download it onto my phone**

... and the list goes on and on.

this kind of problem could be solved as below

`(on_Prep|to_Prep|...)`

But in some situations, this problem occurs with determiners such as

**Eat the food**

**Eat food**

I know the meaning of the above sentences is not exactly the same but is there any way to accomplish such a goal?

I tried the following but it seemed unlogical.

```
mkNP
    (the_Det|)
    (mkN ("food"))
```

I also tried to add an empty string for determiner such as `mkDet (mkDigits (""))`
but unfortunately, the above two ways seem not smart enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general approach with using `|` is correct.

There is no empty determiner, but rather [another overload instance of `mkNP`](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html#NP). There's one with a determiner (so `Det -> N -> NP`) and another without, just `N -> NP`. So you can do this:

```hs
eat_food_VP : VP = 
  mkVP eat_V2 (mkNP the_Det food_N | mkNP food_N) ;
```